# Invalid form saving its data

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm currently stuck on a problem and I can't seem to find the light at the end of the tunnel.

I have a kind of simple controller function:

```
public function settingsAction(Request $request)
{
    $org = $this->getUser()->getOrganisation();
    $form = $this->createForm(new OrgSettingsType(), $org);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
            $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
            $dm->persist($this->getUser()->getOrganisation());
            $dm->flush();
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'msg.changes_saved');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('metacloud_account_organisation_settings'));
    }

    if ($form->isSubmitted())
    {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('danger', 'msg.update_failed_see_errors');
    }

    return $this->render('MetaCloudAccountBundle:Organisation:settings.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView() ));
}
```

The form isn't really more complex, but it's a two level form :

```
class OrgSettingsType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('groups', 'collection', array(
        'type'   => 'text',
        'allow_add' => true,
        'options' => array(
            'label' => false
        )
    ));

    $builder->add('cloudAccounts', 'cloud_account', array(
    ));

    $builder->add('settings', new OrganisationConfigType());
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'MetaCloud\DataBundle\Document\Organisation',
        'cascade_validation' => true,
        'validation_groups' => array('account_edit', 'Default')
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'org_config';
}
}
```

The *OrganisationConfigType* form is simple enough and is linked to a document *OrganisationConfig* where the constraints are declared in the form of annotations.

The problem is that when I submit the form, even though the data is incorrect and the form says so, it still persists the modification in the database. My understanding of the thing was that a form wouldn't persist any data by itself and would just compare data with the constraint annotations I have set up. I don't want to flood the question so I'm not showing all my code, but if you need any more information please ask and I will edit !

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: someone asked for my entity code: I post it here, without the irrelevant getters and setters.

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="societe", repositoryClass="MetaCloud\DataBundle\Repository\OrganisationRepository")
 * @MongoDB\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @Unique("email")
 */
class Organisation
{

/**
 * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="AUTO", name="_id")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @MongoDB\String(name="nom")
 *
 * @Assert\NotNull(message="error name")
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @MongoDB\String(name="siret", nullable=true)
 *
 *
 */
protected $number;

/**
 * @MongoDB\String(name="nomRep")
 *
 * @Assert\NotNull(
 *     message = "contact last name cant be null"
 *  )
 */
protected $contactLastName;

/**
 * @MongoDB\String(name="prenomRep")
 *
 * @Assert\NotNull(message="error contact first name")
 */
protected $contactFirstName;

/**
 * @MongoDB\String(name="titreRep", nullable=true)
 */
protected $contactTitle;

/**
 * @MongoDB\String(name="civilite")
 *
 * @Assert\NotNull(message="civilite is null")
 */
protected $contactHonorific;

/**
 * @MongoDB\String(name="email")
 *
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 * @Assert\Email()
 */
protected $email;

/**
 * @MongoDB\String(name="emailadmin", nullable = true)
 *
 * @Assert\Email()
 */
protected $emailAdmin = "";

/**
 * @MongoDB\String(name="telephone")
 *
 * @Assert\NotNull
 */
protected $phone;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Int(name="maxutilisateurs")
 *
 * @Assert\NotNull(groups={"account_edit"})
 * @Assert\Range(min=1, groups={"account_edit"})
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 */
protected $maxUsers;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Int(name="restutilisateurs", nullable=true)
 */
protected $remainingUsers;

/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="Contract", name="contract", nullable=true)
 */
protected $contract;

/**
 * @MongoDB\String(name="datecreated")
 */
protected $createdAt;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Date(name="datedeleted", nullable=true)
 */
protected $deletedAt;


/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="Address", name="adresse")
 *
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
protected $address;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Collection(name="groupes", nullable=true)
 *
 */
protected $groups = array();

/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="Administrator", name="administrateur")
 */
protected $administrator;

/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="User", name="mappedadmin")
 * 
 * @Gedmo\ReferenceIntegrity("nullify")
 */
protected $mappedAdmin;

/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="OrganisationConfig", name="configpublique", nullable=true)
 */
protected $settings;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Collection(name="cloudstockages", nullable=true)
 *
 * @Assert\Count(min=1, groups={"account_edit"})
 */
protected $cloudAccounts = array();

/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="User", mappedBy="organisation", nullable=true)
 *
 * @Gedmo\ReferenceIntegrity("nullify")
 */
protected $users;


/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="SecurityCode", mappedBy="organisation", nullable=true)
 *
 * @Gedmo\ReferenceIntegrity("nullify")
 */
protected $invites;

/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Organisation", mappedBy="integrator", name="organisations", nullable=true)
 */
protected $organisations;

/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Organisation", inversedBy="organisations", name="integrator", simple="true")
 */
protected $integrator;


/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="boolean", name="anintegrator")
 *
 */
protected $anIntegrator;

/**
 * Determine if there are enough accounts to provide Confidentiality
 *
 * @Assert\True(
 *   message = "org_not_enough_accounts_for_confidentiality",
 *   groups={"account_edit"}
 * )
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isEnoughCloudAccountsForConfidentiality()
{
    if(null === $this->getSettings()) {
        return true;
    }

    if('NO' != $this->getSettings()->getIntegrity() && null !== $this->getSettings()->getIntegrity()) {
        // validate if getIntegrity is selected as it has a higher level validation rule
        return true;
    }

    if('NO' != $this->getSettings()->getConfidentiality() && null !== $this->getSettings()->getConfidentiality()) {
        return count($this->cloudAccounts) >= 1;
    }

    return true;
}
/**
 * Determine if there are enough accounts to provide Integrity
 *
 * @Assert\True(
 *   message = "org_not_enough_accounts_for_integrity",
 *   groups={"account_edit"}
 * )
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isEnoughCloudAccountsForIntegrity()
{
    if(null === $this->getSettings()) {
        return true;
    }

    if('NO' != $this->getSettings()->getIntegrity() && null !== $this->getSettings()->getIntegrity()) {
        return count($this->cloudAccounts) >= 2;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with invalid data? I can't see any "special" validation.

Comment: The embedded form has constraint. Like, some fields are required to be set to false if some other fields aren't superior to three. The errors, when presents, are correctly displayed (meaning I get my message "msg.update_failed_see_errors", meaning the form is not valid, but the data still changes in the database

Comment: So you got a flash message "msg.changes_saved", too?

Comment: No. But the data still is saved in database. It confuses the hell out of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. As a matter of fact, Symfony validator service only **says** the data is invalid but doesn't refresh the modified entity in database. All I had to do was to refresh the object associated to the form in order to make things work :

```
if ($form->isSubmitted())
{
    $dm->refresh($org);
    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('danger', 'msg.update_failed_see_errors');
}
```

If anyone has the same problem, interesting sources can be found here :

[Google groups discussion about the problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/kto13ZgH3CA)
[Ticket on the subject for symfony2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5480)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. You do this :

```
$dm->persist($this->getUser()->getOrganisation());
```

You should do that :

```
$dm->persist($org);
```

Indeed, the from validation is linked to the variable $org, not the reference to the object, I think. Try and tell us :)

Comment: Tried it, and it's not it. As I see the problem, since I don't even enter in this conditional code (my form is invalid), I don't think the problem is at this level. Thanks for your time though :)

Comment: Yes, indeed, that was stupid, sorry ! Just to be sure we understand what happens : you get your danger flashbag and the whole object is persisted in database (not just the sub-object OrganisationConfig) ?

Comment: The whole object is saved, I just checked it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the persist operation in your controller has nothing to do with the form itself. Your forms underlying data_class is 'MetaCloud\DataBundle\Document\Organisation', are you sure, that

`$org = $this->getUser()->getOrganisation();`

returns an object of type 'MetaCloud\DataBundle\Document\Organisation'? To clarify things, please post your entities code.

Edit: Also try to add 
`$org = $form->getData();`
before you persist the data.

Comment: I am sure that getOrganisation() returns the correct kind of object, the form wouldn't be able to build otherwise as I have no other document of this structure (the getter would return an error). My entity code is really long, I'll see what I can do.